# play framework plugins can't be recognized by eclipse

Tags: eclipse, playframework

I use play framework 2.2.1 and eclipse kepler service release 2.

I installed some play framework plugins like secure social and reactive mongo. It compiles fine when i run play compile. However, eclipse doesn't recognize these plugions and shows red cross symbols. How to fix this?

```
import securesocial.core.SecureSocial
import securesocial.core.Identity
import securesocial.core.Identity
```

Comment: did you perform `play eclipse` again after including new dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Try running "play clean", "play deps", "play ec" and then refresh your eclipse project.